# Uninstalling older java version from mac os x el capitan

Tags: java, macos, osx-elcapitan

I have installed `jdk 8` update 92 on my macbook which had `jdk 1.6.0` installed in it. Now I want to uninstall the `java sdk 1.6.0` files from location `"/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions"` but when I try to do so a error gets prompt saying " “1.6.0” can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by OS X.".

So please tell me how to remove these files.

Comment: I'm not a mac user but I guess "can’t be modified or deleted because it’s required by OS X." is your answer.

Comment: I understand what it mentions.
But the problem is that when I deploy my project Mobile Application Framework project using Oracle Jdeveloper, an error occurs saying that can't find the required javac file bcoz it is still stuck with jdk 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the `JAVA_HOME`, you can have installed both of `jdk`'s but it is important that which one is selected as your `JAVA_HOME`. Once you change it, there is no need to delete the unused ones and they can be there without deleting them.

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/731099/550403) you can find a good tutorial to do so.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml worked for me:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin

sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane
```